# How can I use prepared statement and, mysqli to create a while loop?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get messages sent to a user by others and output them all through a while loop. However the current system I have doesn't output anything at all?

I searched this site for a solution and each one I found I would try but to no avail. I have tried multiple fetch methods and can't seem to figure it out.

This is the main script that does the magic

```php
$userid=$_SESSION['id'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user2_id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $userid);
$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->get_result();
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();

//echo $row['message_text'];


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<p>".$row['message_text']."</p>";
}
```

No error messages show up at all.

Comment: what happen if you comment this line `$row=$result->fetch_assoc();` ?

Comment: It solves everything